# Why does Google Search Results differ when logged in and logged out?

Tags: seo, google, search-results

I have noticed when I am logged into my Google account and type my domain into Google search the results differ from than when I'm not logged in. For example when I'm logged in my site is 1st and when I'm logged out... it's 5th...

*Why do search results differ when logged in?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is pretty simple. When you are logged in, Google sorts the results according to your search habits and your [search history](http://www.google.com/history).
For this reason, the results you browse/click the most are likely to be moved at the top of the SERP when you are logged in.

Answer (score 1):

[Google customizes search results based on your search history](http://searchengineland.com/google-now-personalizes-everyones-search-results-31195). So similar but different different search results will be shown for different users based on their search history. If you want to see what the general public sees when they search be sure to log out of your Google account when searching.